# Pagination links not working correctly

Tags: php, forms, pagination

Hi! I want to paginate results from a HTML form. Everything works fine until I actually click the links that should take me to the next set of results. Here is the PHP side of my form:

```
<?php
/*########################## D.B Connection ##########################*/
include("db_conex.php");    
/*########################## Error reporting ##########################*/   
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
/*########################## Set output to default at zero ##########################*/
$search_output = "";
/*########################## Pagination Script ##########################*/
/*########################## Input  Clean ##########################*/
$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
// Query one get total no of rows
if($_POST['filter1'] == "nsw"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nsw WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "nt"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nt WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "qld"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM qld WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "sa"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sa WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "vic"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vic WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "tas"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tas WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "wa"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM wa WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "act"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT COUNT(id) FROM act WHERE type = '$searchquery' ";
}   
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand , $mysqlConnection);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
//total row count
$rows = $row[0];
//number of results displayed on each page
$page_rows =1;
//this tells us the page number of Our last page
$last =ceil($rows/$page_rows);
//ensures $last can not be less than 1
if($last < 1)
    $last=1;
//determine page number
$pagenum = 1;
//Get pagenum from URL variable if present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn']))
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);       
//makes sure pagenum is not below 1 our more than Our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1){
    $pagenum = 1;
}
else if ($pagenum > $last){
    $pagenum = $last;
}   
//set range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum    
$limit = 'LIMIT '.($pagenum - 1)* $page_rows.','.$page_rows;
//sql query again
/*########################## Input Check & Clean ##########################*/
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "")
    {
//$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    }
//$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM nt WHERE type = 'diesel mechanic' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
/*########################## sql query  ##########################*/
if($_POST['filter1'] == "nsw"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM nsw WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "nt"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM nt WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "qld"){
    $sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM qld WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "sa"){
$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM sa WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
}
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "vic")
        {
$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM vic WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit"; 
         }
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "tas")
         {
$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM tas WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
         }
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "wa")
          {
$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM wa WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit"; 
          }
else if($_POST['filter1'] == "act")
          {
$sqlCommand = " SELECT company , ref , title , description ,address , date_added FROM act WHERE type = '$searchquery' ORDER BY date_added DESC  $limit";
         }
/*########################## End Sql Query ##########################*/
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand , $mysqlConnection);
// displays current page number and total number of pages
$tline1 = "Results: (<b>$rows</b>)";
$tline2 = "Job <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";    
//Establish $pagination variables
$paginationCtrls = '';
//if there is more than 1 page of results
if($last !=1)
        {
            //check which page we are on and displaying link or not.
            if($pagenum>1)
            {
                $previous = $pagenum -1;
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
                //make clickable number links: left side
                for($i = $pagenum-1; $i < $pagenum; $i++)
                    {
                        if($i > 0)
                        {
                            $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
                        }
                    }
            }
            //show current page number without link function
            $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
            //make clickable number links: right side
            for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <=$last; $i++)
                    {
                        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
                        if($i >=$pagenum=4)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
//check to see if we are on last page
if ($pagenum != $last)
            {
                $next = $pagenum + 1;
                $paginationCtrls .= '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href ="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
            }                   
        }
        //how many records in DB        
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 0){
$search_output .= "<hr >results for <strong>'$searchquery'</strong><hr >";
$list = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
            $id = $row["ref"];
             $id1 = $row["company"];
             $id2 = $row["description"];
             $id3 =$row["date_added"];
             $id4 =$row["title"];
             $id5 =$row["address"];
/*############# End Execute Command #############*/     

   $search_output .= "<div class ='result'><span class ='ref'>Job ref no: $id </span><br><br><b>Company: </b>$id1<br><br><b>Location: </b>$id5<br><br><b>Date posted: </b>$id3<br><br><b>Job Title: </b>$id4<br><br><br><b>Job Description</b><br><br> $id2<br></div><br><br>";

                } // close while

            }
            else 
        {
$search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
        }

/*############# End OutPut #############*/  
// Close your database connection 
//mysqli_close($mysqlConnection);

?>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: instead of a list of elseif statements use a switch statement http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: In addition to @andrew, it's better to check your coding style, it's been so far for readability, and editability too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
```

You use $_POST to fetch the search query, and the POST data disappears when you navigate to another page (i.e. clicks one of the pagination links). So you need to include the query as a GET parameter in the pagination URLs:

```
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].
            '?pn='.$i.'&amp;searchquery='.$searchquery.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
```

And you need to fetch the query from both $_POST and $_GET:

```
    if (isset($_POST['searchquery'])) {
            $searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['searchquery'])) {
            $searchquery = $_GET['searchquery'];
    } else {
            // Invalid request, error handling code here
    }

    // Safety precautions
    $searchquery = strip_tags($searchquery);
```

NB: you should also escape the query when you use it in your MySQL queries or injections will be possible! Read more: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string . Or even better, use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**EDIT 09.09.13:** You need to do the same thing for the $_POST['filter']